# What do I use for the Wizards nature skill modifier?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

In the PHB on page 156 the Wizard says that it's nature skill modifier is INT.
But on the actual Character sheet itself the nature skill modifier is WIS.

[image: PHB pg.156]

Just wondering which one I am supposed to use. Or is it that the Wizard can choose either or?

Comment: If you have the original 4E Core there is a lot, and I mean *a lot*, of errata. Your best bet is to pick up a copy of the *Rules Compendium* as it is up-to-date on the errata. It is under the Essentials line and should be pretty easy to find. I think it's only around $14 too.

Comment: I concur with Blob, that book is an amazing reference. It's also small enough to be handy around the gaming table for when you need to look up a quick rule.

Comment: Just bought the book from eBay. 16$ not bad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**It's a typo.**

If you have a look at the [official Errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf), it says the following:

> **Trained Skills**
>
> Page 156: Replace
>   "Nature (Int)" with "Nature  (Wis)."

Answer (score 4):

Rules Compendium, p148, lists Nature as a Wisdom-based Skill. Must be an errata in the PHB.